# How can I 'like' a wordpress post using python?

Tags: python, wordpress, post

So, I have a wordpress blog and I want to 'like' a post from another wordpress blog (to which I have the url)
Is there a way I can do it using python?
I do know how to post in my own blog using wordpresslib but I don´t see, using that lib, how could I login and then 'like' a wordpress post (from another blog which is not mine)...is there a way I can do that USING PYTHON (not manually)?
Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/. Start a session, login to wordpress, send whatever information gets sent when you like the post in your browser

Comment: Did I break any rules of the site with my question? I don´t get it Pedro Lobito

Comment: I want to do it programaticly,using python...not manually...isn´t that clear?

Comment: @Racialz gave you the answer